# Find the change of electromotive-force per degree, at 15 degrees, 20 degrees, and 25 degrees.

Tags: calculus

I started to read "Calculus Made Easy", by Silvanus P. Thompson, and i can't figure out how to solve one problem

E = 1.4340[1 - 0.000814(t-15)+0.0000007(t-15)^2] volts

Find the change of electromotive-force per degree, at 15 degrees, 20 degrees, and 25 degrees.

I try to derive like this:

de/dt = 1.4340[(7*(t-15)/5.10^6)+0.999168]

However when i assigned the degrees in t i get completely different results as those on the book. How to solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you read the equation to contain $(1 - 0.000814)(t-15)$, not $1 - 0.000814(t-15)$, which is where your $0.999168$ comes from.

Comment: It's might be my mistake. it shouldn't be 0.999168 then right? the 1 dissolves?

Comment: The derivative of $1$ is zero, but then the coefficient multiplying $t$ is $-0.000814$, so that should be the term not multiplying $(t-15)$ in the derivative.

Comment: You right. Thank you.